# unset() static variable doesn't work?

Tags: php, unset

See this code:
http://codepad.org/s8XnQJPN

```
function getvalues($delete = false)
{
   static $x;
   if($delete)
   {
      echo "array before deleting:\n";
      print_r($x);
      unset($x);
   }
   else
   {
      for($a=0;$a<3;$a++)
      {
         $x[]=mt_rand(0,133);
      }
   }
}

getvalues();
getvalues(true); //delete array values
getvalues(true); //this should not output array since it is deleted
```

Output:

```
array before deleting:
Array
(
    [0] => 79
    [1] => 49
    [2] => 133
)
array before deleting:
Array
(
    [0] => 79
    [1] => 49
    [2] => 133
)
```

Why is the array, `$x` not being deleted when it is being unset?

Comment: do $x = null; outside of the function to unset it. In my case the syntax was class_name::$static_property = null;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a static variable is unset, it destroys the variable only in the function in which it is unset. The following calls to the function (getValues()) will make use of the value before it was unset.

This is mentioned the documentation of the unset function as well.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Is there a way to destroy the static variable?

Comment: Where $delete is true then I think u can make $x = null before you use unset($x); This way you the next time the function is called it will use null as the value for $x as it was the last value of $x before it was unset.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

> If a static variable is unset() inside of a function, unset() destroys
>   the variable only in the context of the rest of a function. Following
>   calls will restore the previous value of a variable.

```
function foo()
{
    static $bar;
    $bar++;
    echo "Before unset: $bar, ";
    unset($bar);
    $bar = 23;
    echo "after unset: $bar\n";
}

foo();
foo();
foo();
```

The above example will output:

```
Before unset: 1, after unset: 23
Before unset: 2, after unset: 23
Before unset: 3, after unset: 23
```

Comment: I did not know this... how can I destroy the variable then?