# Static variable in method doesn't reset on instance unset

Tags: php, oop, testing, static, static-variables

Interesting behavior in PHP 5.6.12-arm and PHP 7 RC3 (though I guess it's like that in all version, I just wanted to note which versions I've used to test):

#### Example - using a static variable inside class method

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function Bar() {
        static $var = 0;

        return ++$var;
    }
}

$Foo_instance = new Foo;

print $Foo_instance->Bar(); // prints 1
print PHP_EOL;

unset($Foo_instance);

$Foo_instance2 = new Foo;

print $Foo_instance2->Bar(); // prints 2 - but why?
print PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Question: How can a 2 be printed**, since we unseted the whole instance before calling Foo->Bar() again?

Please note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443753/unset-static-variable-doesnt-work) question and its answers don't answer my question.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in the php documentation of [variables scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#59676).

> if you declare a variable as static inside a function, it's static for
> the whole class and all of its instances, not for each object.

So, a static variable is not related to a single instance.