# How do I Destroy a Static Variable in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, static

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443753/unset-static-variable-doesnt-work) say that `unset()` doesn't work, but weren't clear on what does. I have a recursive function, which uses static variables, however after the recursion has finished and the value has been returned, I need to reset those variables or subsequent calls (the recursive function is currently been called within a loop) would return wrong values.

In the linked question some people suggested trying `$var = NULL` outside the function which I did, but to seemingly no effect.

The reason why I used static variables and didn't just write them as parameters to the function is that I don't want a situation where the user can pass in arguments to that function, as the only arguments to the function should be supplied from within it.

---

#### My Code

```
<?
    require_once("randX.php");  #"randX()" generates a random floating point number in a specified range.
    // require_once("../displayArray.php");  
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

/*
*   Generates a valid, random probability distribution for a given array of elements, that can be used in conjunction with "probSelect()".
*   Input: 
        $arr: An array of elements.
        $control: A value that decides how much mass is allowed to be unilaterally dumped onto one element. A high value would permit distributions where most of the mass is concentrated on one element. 
        If an invalid value is provided, the default is used.
*   Output: An associative array where the keys are the elements in the original array, and the values are their probabilities. 
*   @param array $arr:  An array of elements for which the probability distribution would be generated. 
*   @param float $control: A variable which limits the inequality of the probability distribution.
*/
    function probGen(array $arr, float $control = 0.01) 
    {
        $control = ($control <= 1 && $control >= 0)?($control):(0.00001);   #Use the default value if an invalid number is supplied.
        static $result = [];    #Initialises $result with an empty array on first function call.
        static $max = 1;    #Initialises $max with 1 on first function call.
        foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
            $x = randX(0, $max);    #Random probability value.
            $result[$value] = ($result[$value] + $x)??0;    #Initialise the array with 0 on first call, and on subsequent calls increment by $x to assign probability mass.
            $max -= $x;     #Ensures that the probability never sums to more than one.
        }
/*
*   After the execution of the above code, there would be some leftover probability mass. 
*   The code below adds it to a random element.
*/
        $var = array_values($arr);
        if($max <= $control)    #To limit concentration of most of the probability mass in one variable.
        {
            $result[$var[rand(0,(count($var)-1))]] += $max; #Selects a random key and adds $max to it.
            // print("<br>Sum: ".array_sum($result)."<br>");
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return probGen($arr, $control); 
        }
    }
    $max = NULL;        
    unset($max);
    $result = NULL; 
    unset($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is always the problem with using `static` in any circumstances, I would change them to be parameters being passed in and having a default value...

```
function probGen(array $arr, float $control = 0.01, $result = [], $max = 1 )
```

(With the appropriate types).

These can then be passed down the chain in your further call...

```
return probGen($arr, $control, $result, $max);
```

This allows you better control over what these values start as (you can pass in your own values as a default) as well as being able to reset/adjust them as part of the call.

Comment: Noted, I had considered this but thought it might be inconvenient as it allows the user to pass in values for those parameters which they are not supposed to do. How would you suggest I implement that.